# Is there any way Vue keep-alive to achieve forward refresh, back does not refresh?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 pages in vue, when I go from page 1 to page 2 and I go back to page 1 is there any way the data still won't refresh?
Thanks for watching, looking forward to receiving your help

Answer (score 1):

You can check the usage *"keepalive"*

[Vue 2 Dynamic & Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

You can use like this:

```
<keep-alive>
    /*components*/
</keep-alive>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use keep-alive for a view page and not a component? Thank you for the reply